# How to check if request is made from Excel/PowerBI

Tags: c#, http-headers, httprequest

I've made an API but wanted to know if there's a way to check if the incoming request is coming from an app like Excel/PowerBI.

I've researched a bit but all I'm finding is ways to identify the browser which uses the User-Agent.

Can I use the User-Agent header for Excel/PowerBI? I'm unable to run the API locally (that's another issue which I don't want to go into today) so I can't debug it to see the incoming request and I'm unsure how I can investigate the request Headers from Excel/PowerBI.

Comment: You can use an application like `Fiddler` to inspect outgoing requests from an application. And yes `User-Agent` may give you an idea if the excel adds it (or it might not add anything) but anything can replicate that as it is a customizable header (So at best it will cause some security issues). A better approach is to require authentication and provide identities that can differentiate the caller.

Comment: There's already authentication set up for the API I just wanted to know what apps/browsers the users are using to retrieve the data so that we could focus more of our future tech towards that. I've found out that both Excel and PowerBI make the request via Power Query and the User-Agent for that is: ```Microsoft.Data.Mashup (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=304225) ``` so we won't be able to distinguish between the 2 via User-Agent alone. Is there anything else?